# Undefined Method 'original_path' Rails 3.0.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was previously using Rails '3.0.0.rc' but just upgraded to 3.0.4. When I import a csv file, I now see an error:

```
undefined method `original_path' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000100ae5398>
```

Have had a look around and can't see what I'm supposed to alter in the later version of rails.

I can post files if required.

Bob

Comment: Remove the access to method/property "original_path" which you use in one controller. "grep -rl original_path [Rails root]/app/" shows you where you use that method. Rails tells you there is no such method/property.

Answer (score 3):

You should now use `original_filename`